# Is there a way decouple views from view models like the following?

Tags: swiftui, combine

My target is 2 thing:
1. to make a view depending on a view model protocol not a concrete class.
2. a sub view gets the view model from the environment instead of passing it through the view hierarchy
I've mentioned my goals so if there's a totally different way to achieve them, I'm open to suggestion.
Here's what've tried and failed of course and raised weird error:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: some ViewModelProtocol

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Enter something...", text:$viewModel.text)
            Text(viewModel.greetings)
        }
    }
}

//MARK:- View Model
protocol ViewModelProtocol: ObservableObject {
    var greetings: String { get }
    var text: String { get set }
}

class ConcreteViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    var greetings: String { "Hello everyone..!" }
    @Published var text = ""
}

//MARK:- Usage
let parent = ContentView().environmentObject(ConcreteViewModel())
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, but it's not very pretty.

You're running into issues, since the compiler can't understand how it's ever supposed to infer what *type* that that `some protocol` should be.

The reason why `some` works in declaring your view, is that it's inferred from the type of whatever you supply to it.

If you make your view struct take a generic viewmodel type, then you can get this up and compiling.

```
struct MyView<ViewModel: ViewModelProtocol>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.greetings)
    }
}
```

the bummer here, is that you now have to declare the *type* of viewmodel whenever you use this view, like so:

```
let test: MyView<ConcreteViewModel> = MyView()
```

Comment: Exactly. I didn't want the content view to know anything about the "MyView" view model concrete type. Actually I was trying to escape the generic solution, couldn't find a away. so I decided to post a question . thanks for trying to help.